# Database Replication Issue

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication, mysql-5.6

We had two MySQL 5.6.35 Server in our organization working as Master/Slave replication. The replication was working fine in this situation. But we have a new requirement to place another server which will be replicated from the slave server.

**For example:**

**Server1** - Will work as master

**Server2** - Will work as slave in Server1 perspective and will work as master in **Server3**

**Server3** - Will act as slave and will receive replication from **Server2**

Kindly help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for Master --> Relay --> Slave.  This is quite possible.

1. Server2: `STOP SLAVE`
2. Server2: Pretend it is a Master and do the operations necessary to add its first Slave (Server3).  (Dump data Server2, copy to Server3, etc)
3. Server2: `START SLAVE`

Be sure to turn on `log_slave_updates` and `log_bin` and have different `server-id`.

Why do you want M->R->S?  It is a rather unusual setup.  Is it the start of something more grandiose?  I ask because there may be other tips to impart.